# Python/Pandas - comparing data in single rows from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i have tried to write the program which would comparing data with two single rows in excel, if in row is more than one world I split it and put the sigle words to arrays.

It works a bit :) but some of the rows still stays as ampty without inserted "well" or "bad" I dont know why. I also want to have the possibility the insert "well" if for axample 3 of 4 variables from arrays would be the same.

Bellow you can find my code, thak you for the support.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = (pd.read_excel("numtest.xlsx", "Arkusz1"))


for i in range (0, 9005):
    try:
        a = df.iloc[i, 1]
        b = df.iloc[i, 2]
        x = a.split()
        y = b.split()

        data_1 = {'TYPE': x}
        data_2 = {'TYPE': y} 

        if np.array_equal(data_1, data_2):
            df.iloc[i, 3] = 'well'
    except:
        df.iloc[i, 3] = 'bad'
df.to_excel("numtest2.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet3")
```

Comment: Could you please share the data of your `numtest.xlsx` , at least a little sample? (not as image, copy/paste the data to your question)

Comment: I share it in my github: https://github.com/mZadrzynski/Python_Data/commit/cad57e5acd0769195576683ad9b66427d9c4217d

Answer (score 0):

you are only updating the third column with bad if there is an exception not if there is a mismatch,  you need to change your code slightly like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = (pd.read_excel("numtest.xlsx", "Arkusz1"))


for i in range (0, 9005):
    try:
        a = df.iloc[i, 1]
        b = df.iloc[i, 2]
        x = a.split()
        y = b.split()

        data_1 = {'TYPE': x}
        data_2 = {'TYPE': y} 

        if np.array_equal(data_1, data_2):
            df.iloc[i, 3] = 'well'
        else:
            df.iloc[i, 3] = 'bad'
    except:
        df.iloc[i, 3] = 'very-bad'   # something went wrong in parsing the data

df.to_excel("numtest2.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet3")
```